# How to loop through directories in powershell and move the directories?

Tags: powershell

I have a directory structure that looks like this :

- Root

  - Older

I want to parse all folders in root and move them the Older subfolder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get-childitem (gci)` to get all childitems of the root-folder (`$root`), and move them (`move-item`) to the new destination. You just have to make sure, you will not move the destination itself, therefore we check that.

```
$root = "C:\temp\root"
$destination = "older"

gci $root | ? {$_.name -ne $destination} | move-item -Destination "C:\temp\root\$destination" -force
```

Comment: How can I make it fail if the folder exists in the destination?

Comment: just cut of the `-force` Parameter in the `move-item` Statement and add an `-erroraction silentlycontinue` to avoid a red error message